# Why don't Venn diagrams count as formal proofs?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Just curious. If the purpose of a proof is to inform and persuade, why don't Venn diagrams count? Is it just convention or is there a more, umm, formal reason haha. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, what kind of statement could you prove using ven diagrams?

Comment: @Karolis I'm in an intro discrete math course, so I'm thinking really simple stuff like set identities.

Comment: Maybe he's drawing $(A\cap B)^c$ as a diagram (or sequence of diagrams), and $A^c\cup B^c$ as a diagram and saying "they're equal!".

Comment: The utility of Venn diagrams evaporates when you look at four sets rather than just three.

Comment: Not if you draw them like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Venn%27s_four_ellipse_construction.svg

Comment: Ian Stewart, [*The truth about Venn diagrams*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3615644), The Mathematical Gazette
Vol. 60, No. 411 (Mar., 1976), pp. 47-54, points out that Venn diagrams ‘can be made rigorous by the rigorous by proving the right “metatheorem”’.

Comment: @JoeZeng: I hadn't seen that before. Thanks. Although my point stands for 5 or more sets I am sure.

Comment: @JimConant Not for five. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Symmetrical_5-set_Venn_diagram.svg

Comment: @JoeZeng: nice.

Comment: That's like asking why isn't drawing a picture considered a proof in planimetry. It helps you while solving problem, it helps others reading your solution (proof) but it's not a proof itself.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Nor for 7 or 11 either, or in general for any prime. http://cartesianproduct.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/venn-diagrams-for-11-sets/

Comment: @arkamis: ha! When I'm wrong, I'm wrong in a big way.

Comment: In information theory, there is basically a 1-1 translation between regions in Venn diagrams and entropy terms across collections of 2-4 (5 if you're good) variables. The visualization saves several lines of basic manipulation and often gets the point across quicker and cleaner than if you were to write all the equations out.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you have written, but I would venture to say that anything you "prove" with Venn diagrams probably has an extremely direct translation into set theory, which would certainly be an acceptable form of proof.

The strongest reason to not let you just use a Venn diagram alone is that your teacher probably wants you to verbalize your explanation. This is a key part of mathematics. Drawing a picture can really help illustrate the idea involved, but it does not always explain the connection to the logic you are working within.

There is also a huge drawback to proving things by Venn diagram: your visual preconceptions may fool you into making a mistake. This cannot happen (or happens to a much smaller degree) when you work in the language of set theory.

Answer (score 9):

The point is, you need to take care to be specific about what is being talked about.  Symbols tend to be more specific, but mathematicians still sometimes make equivocation errors in the language.  Really it boils down to not confusing the subjects and objects in a proof.  As some other people have said, a Venn diagram typically applies to one set or another, so to generalize is a risky business.  The same errors can occur in symbolic math manipulation, though. So there is nothing inherently invalid about the type of proof.

Venn diagrams are hardly distinct from proofs in Geometry by drawing figures.

I do agree with the comment that we are just talking about convention. Over the centuries mathematicians have changed their opinions on what constitutes a valid proof.  Some of Euler's work, for example, comes to mind.  It was rather arbitrary for us today to call his proofs weaker than ours today.  Its a cultural chance in mindset, really.

Venn diagrams, geometrical figures... these are just concepts illustrated on paper. Thats it. How is that different than algebraic symbols written on paper? Or English?  Its a language that conveys a concept.  To de-emphasize the worth of one simply because it takes a different form is at best arbitrary and subjective. At worst its irrational or bigoted.  Let me ask you, is there a formal proof as to why figures and shapes and Venn diagrams are less effective than symbols?  It would seem to me that this would require a proof of its own.

Until such time that this is proven, the only criticism I can give the use of any one proof method over another is that we are fallible humans that may not interpret or capture the meaning of the question adequately enough in one system of proof, but we do in another.  Its a failure on our own part.

Answer (score 7):

Using the default Venn diagram with two intersecting circles, it is "evident" that $A\cup B\ne A\cap B$. But of course this statement is not true in general.

Comment: It is evident only if one doesn’t understand Venn diagrams. Any tool can be misused.

Comment: @Brian: I have yet to meet the person who understood Venn diagrams, and had a problem with writing formal proofs.

Comment: @Asaf: I’ve known some who understood Venn diagrams and didn’t see any real need to say more, though they were capable of doing so.

Comment: Written proofs have mistakes too. You haven't justified why this is different. So, -1 actually, since that's the crux of your point.

Answer (score 5):

Using Venn diagrams we can prove set identities with three set variables. Why this is correct?

There is theorem that claim that Boolean algebra $\mathcal{B}$ is free on $X$ for class of Boolean algebras if for all different $x_1,\dots,x_n$ it's true $x_1^{\alpha_1} \wedge x_2^{\alpha_2} \wedge \dots \wedge x_n^{\alpha_n} \neq 0$, where $$x^{\alpha}=\begin{cases}x, ~~~\alpha=1\\ x', ~~\alpha=0\end{cases}$$ So, if $A,B,C \subseteq K$ like on diagram $(V)$,

[image: Picture]

then clearly $A^{\alpha}\cap B^{\beta} \cap C^{\gamma} \neq \emptyset,$ where $$A^{\alpha}=\begin{cases}A, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\alpha=1\\ A^c=K\backslash A, ~~\alpha=0\end{cases}$$ Let $\mathbf{\Omega}=\langle A,B,C \rangle$ be set algebra define with $\cap,\cup,^c$. Using theorem that I mentioned, we see that $\mathbf{\Omega}$ is free algebra on $X=\{A,B,C\}$ for class of Boolean algebras. Now, using theorem 1., every Boolean identity, and therefore every set identity with three variables, it's true in Boolean algebras, and therefore in $\mathscr{P}(X)$.

**Theorem 1.** Let $\mathcal{A}$ is free algebra on $X$, $|X|=n,$ for every class algebras $\mathfrak {M}$ algebraic language $L$. If $u(x_1,\dots,x_n)=v(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is algebraic identity in language $L$ and $u=v$ is true in $\mathcal{A}$, then $u=v$ is also true for all $\mathcal{C} \in \mathfrak{M}.$

But, four circle $A,B,C,D$ can divide plane in fourteen parts (but we want sixteen). So, $A^{\alpha}\cap B^{\beta} \cap C^{\gamma} \cap D^{\delta}= \emptyset$ for some choice of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta.$ So, for every Venn diagrams $V(A,B,C,D)$ it exist set identity $u=v$ that is true in $V(A,B,C,D)$, but which is not correct for some sets.

Comment: The equivalent with four circles is an Euler diagram, but not a [Venn Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#Extensions_to_higher_numbers_of_sets). Venn diagrams can keep this going arbitrarily far, though the symbolic approach becomes much more reasonable  as the diagrams quickly become unwieldy.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#Extensions_to_higher_numbers_of_sets

Comment: This is essentially the same proof published by Ian Stewart in _The truth about Venn diagrams_, The Mathematical Gazette Vol. 60, No. 411 (Mar., 1976), pp. 47-54 (http://www.jstor.org/stable/3615644), although the explanation in the article is more informal and therefore more understanable for someone with little background.

Answer (score 3):

Generally because Venn diagrams only illustrate determined examples, and most proofs you find in elementary set theory are about statements for any set, so if want to use Venn diagrams to prove something that should work for every set, you would have to actually use them for every possible set. If there are infinite sets, you're screwed.

Answer (score 3):

Mh I think Venn-diagrams are very helpful and in fact are the proof on several set identities, I even know mathematicans which accept them as a proof.

Comment: I think you meant to say "I even know analysts".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on teacher. If I was one and could be sure that student understands Venn diagrams **and** has given all steps in constructing both Venn diagrams, I would agree to it.

At the start of course. Later students must learn more formal style of proof, because Venn diagrams is only for very specific problem. Although they can still use Venn diagrams as visual help in constructing proofs if they want. It's actually good and trains intuitions of the set theory.

[Note - I'm not teacher or professor.]

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a proof is *not* to inform or persuade (you might not even have anybody to show your proof to).  The purpose of a proof is *to prove*: in a sequence of small and easily verified, or known to be true, steps to prove some conclusion.

Ideally, a proof should be verifiable by a computer.  You may contrast this with the fact that it is theoretically impossible to write a computer program that would verify if a given statement is *provable*.

---

*Update*: of course this is somewhat circular as a definition, but you cannot really *define* a *proof*.  (You can of course use a metalanguage to define a proof in some other formal language, etc.)  Defining a *proof* as a *persuasion* is just proposing a not completely equivalent plain-language synonym as a "definition".

To address the Venn diagrams, the problem with them is that they are usually hard to convert into a sequence of small easily verifiable steps: either you look at it and *guess* how to *prove*, or not, but a Venn diagram itself is only an *illustration* of a proof.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know about the first paragraph. I think "proof as persuasion" (even if there is nobody else, and it is just persuading yourself of the truth of something) is a better description than the circular "purpose of proof is to prove." Ultimately a proof is a communication of evidence, not just a formal sequence of steps.

Comment: I think it is circular because it does not need a definition.  Every dictionary is eventually circular.

Comment: The problem with circularity is that it doesn't explain anything. It's probably better to have a heuristic description as "persuasion," since then you have more than one log in your raft.

Comment: I tried in other ways, but otherwise you probably just need to learn from examples.  Proving that a definition of a proof defines it can be hard :).

Comment: Oh I totally agree that a real definition of "proof" would be nontrivial. I forgot to mention earlier that this solution will probably not fare well until it actually addresses the point about Venn diagrams.

Comment: I replied to just one of the points in the question, not to the title.  I didn't want to go into an explanation why a Venn diagram can be little helpful for a computer program or hard to transform into a sequence of "small steps".  I think other answers must have addressed this.

Comment: 'Not to inform  or persuade..in a sequence of a small and easily verified or known to be true steps to prove some conclusion". This doesn't really make sense as even that of proof by contradiction is to persuade of what we are doing is correct. It is frankly impossible to determine what some known to be true steps are. What constitutes as a step? What is known to be true? How can you even quantify the meaning of true here? How can you even verify something if in order to verify it you must have something known true, but that it self must be verified. This is rather paradoxical.

Comment: @MichaelMooney, you cannot define proof formally. If you define it formally, it will be just a formal proof, not a real proof.

Comment: @MichaelMooney, by the way, the meaning of "true" also cannot be defined (in terms of other things).  I am talking informally here, but there is a relevant [theorem of Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem) about non-definability of truth in some formal settings. Curiously, Tarski succeeded in [defined truth formally](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tarski-truth/) :).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible reason for not accepting a Venn diagram as a proof.  (Here I am using the term "Venn diagram" as opposed to "Euler diagram".)  If what is to be proven is a set equality, the definition of equality must be met.  What is missing is a logical connection between this equality and the use of Venn diagrams.  The result "If two Venn diagrams give the same picture, then the sets they refer to are equal" would suffice.  So if you haven't proved this or are not allowed to use it, then you would not be allowed to use a Venn diagram to prove your set equality.

Answer (score 0):

A Venn Diagram could be a proof if it captures all possible cases.  In the case above where the author uses A U B does not equal A intersect B is not captured by the standard two circles with an intersection, the proof with Venn Diagrams using only one case (Two circles with a football intersection) isn't complete.  If I want to prove a statement for ANY sets, I must include strange sets like the Cantor set and weird possibilities.  With Venn Diagrams, you will have to prove that you have caught EVERY SINGLE possibility.  This may not be feasible.  Thus, we move to rigorous proof using first principles straight from the definitions and theorems.  Those who said even mathematicians accept Venn Diagrams as proofs, well, I am a mathematician.  There may be a couple reasons.  Maybe the instructor is happy that their students were able to think things through with Venn Diagrams.  Proof writing is hard and the first step is believing what you are trying to prove-which is what Venn Diagrams are for. I (mathematician) would not accept it because of the false message it sends as seen on these threads.  Students may internalize that Venn diagrams are proofs for all situations.