# Show $A\cup B =E \iff \overline A\subset B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> let $A\;, B$ and $C$ be subsets of $E$. show that
>
> $$A\cup B =E \iff \overline A\subset B$$

***Notation :***

> - Absolute complement of $A$:  $\overline A=\mathcal{C}_{E}^{A}=\{ x\in E \mid x\notin A \}$

---

**My thoughts**

- **Method** $1$ : Via  Logic theory

$$A\cup B =E \iff \overline A\subset B$$ we can see that as Tautology in  logic theory and we can prove it by truth table:
$$(A\vee B)\iff ((\neg A)\to B)$$

\begin{array} {|c|}
\hline
A & B & (A\vee B )& \neg A & (\neg A \to B )& [(A\vee B)\iff ((\neg A)\to B) ]\\ \hline
T & T & T & F &  T &  T \\ \hline
T & F & T & F &  T &  T\\ \hline
F & T & T & T &  T &  T\\ \hline
F & F & F & T &  F &  T\\ \hline
\end{array}

- **Method** $2$ : Via  Venn diagram ( *Venn diagram not rigorous so they are not really proofs* )

[image]

I think I have two possibilities to draw Venn diagram for $A\cup B =E \implies \overline A\subset B$

$1$. $B=\overline A\qquad $ ($A\cup B=A\cup \overline A =E \implies \overline A\subset B$   )

$2$. $B=E\qquad $ ($A\cup B=A\cup E =E \implies \overline A\subset B$   )

- **Method** $3$

  1. *First step* : show that : $\overline A\subset B \implies A\cup B =E$

Suppose that $\overline A\subset B$ and let's prove that $ A\cup B =E$

- we have $A \subset E$ and  $B \subset E$ then $$(A\cup B) \subset E\quad (1)$$
- Conversely, let $x\in E $ we have two cases $x\in B $ or $x\notin B$

*First case*: if $x\in B$ then $x\in A\cup B $

*Second case*: if $x\notin B$ then $x\notin \overline A\quad  (\text{since}\; \overline A \subset B )$ thus $x\in A $

Therefore $x\in A\cup B $ so in both cases we have :
$$x\in E\implies  x\in A\cup B$$
Therefore
$$E\subset (A\cup B)\quad (2) $$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we conclude that $$E=A\cup B$$

2. *Second step* : show that : $A\cup B =E \implies  \overline A\subset B$

Suppose that $A\cup B=E$ and  and let's prove that $\overline A\subset B$
Let $x\in \overline A$ we have:
\begin{align*}
x\in \overline A &\implies x\in E \\
&\implies x\in A\cup B \\
&\implies x\in B (\;\text{since}\; x\notin A  )\\ 
x\in \overline A &\implies x\in B 
\end{align*}
Therefore 
 $$A\cup B =E \implies  \overline A\subset B$$

Conclusion:

$$A\cup B =E \iff \overline A\subset B$$

---

- Is my proof correct also I'm interested in more ways of proving it

Comment: The [relative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) $\overline{A}$ in OP is usually written as $E\setminus A$.

Comment: it's Absolute complement $\overline A $

Comment: No reason why Venn diagrams are not rigorous. With a little care in the definitions and axioms to prevent hidden assumptions.

Comment: this is why http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304173/why-dont-venn-diagrams-count-as-formal-proofs

Comment: actually it  is not Venn diagram, it is Eiler diagram

Comment: would you provide me reference please

Comment: for instance http://blog.stevemould.com/venn-vs-euler-diagrams/

Answer (score 1):

- if $x\in \bar{A}$, then $x\not \in A$, therefor by $A\cup B=E$, we have $x\in B$, so $\bar{A}\subseteq B$.
- If $\bar{A} \subseteq B$, then $A\cup \bar{A}\subseteq A\cup B$, so $E\subseteq A\cup B$, therefore $A\cup B =E$.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

$A\cup B=E\;$ then $\; E/A \subseteq A \cup B\;$ and then $\;E/A \subseteq B\;$ because $\;E/A\;$ isn't a a subset of $A$ by definition.

And if:$\quad E/A \subseteq B\;$ then $\; A\cup E/A\subseteq A\cup B\;$. Hence $A\cup B=E$