# Question about calculation of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here I want to prove of find a counter example of the statements:

if $A, B, C$ are all sets, then
$$
(A\setminus(B∩C))\setminus(B\setminus C)=A\setminus B
$$
To prove these I draw a Venn diagram
[image]

I think it's true but how can I prove it.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry I forgot to add the "\" between these two things

Comment: Your Venn diagram can be the illustration for a proof if you annotate it to show the intermediate sets on the left side of the equality.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304173/why-dont-venn-diagrams-count-as-formal-proofs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do it by parts. To begin with, one has that
\begin{align*}
A - (B\cap C) & = A\cap(\overline{B\cap C}) = A\cap(B^{c}\cup C^{c}) = (A\cap B^{c})\cup(A\cap C^{c})
\end{align*}

Now we can approach the whole expression:
\begin{align*}
(A - B\cap C)-(B - C) & = ((A\cap B^{c})\cup(A\cap C^{c}))-(B\cap C^{c})\\\\
& = ((A\cap B^{c})\cup(A\cap C^{c}))\cap (B^{c}\cup C)\\\\
& = ((A\cap B^{c})\cap(B^{c}\cap C))\cup((A\cap C^{c})\cap(B^{c}\cup C))\\\\
& = (A\cap B^{c}\cap C)\cup((A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c})\cup\varnothing)\\\\
& = (A\cap B^{c}\cap C)\cup(A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c})\\\\
& = (A\cap B^{c})\cap(C\cup C^{c})\\\\
& = A\cap B^{c} = A - B
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!